# Paypal IPN Not Updating Or Inserting Into Database

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

So I'm using PayPals IPN, But it's not updating the database. It should update the users table, And insert a row into the transactions table. It's doing neither of them. It's sending successful IPN's to paypal, But isn't updating anything. Here's the code:

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<?php require 'connect.php' ?>
<?php
// check if logged into PsychoWars
if(!$id) {
    die('Error: Not Logged In! Contact Us With The Transaction ID!'); 
}

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
 $errmsg = '';   // stores errors from fraud checks
// PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
// 1. Make sure the payment status is "Completed" 
    if ($_POST['payment_status'] != 'Completed') { 
        // simply ignore any IPN that is not completed
        exit(0); 
    } 
}

else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

$email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$password = mt_rand(1000, 9999);
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

// Checking email
if($receiver_email != 'bad.karma12323@gmail.com') {
    die('Error: Paypal Email Doesn\'t Match!');
}
// Bought $1
if($payment_amount == '1.00') {
$points_amount = '500';
$points_energy = '500'; 
$points_name = '500 Points And 500 Energy';
// Update Database
$update_user = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points=(points+".$points_amount."),energy=(energy+".$points_energy.") WHERE id=".$id."");
$add_trans = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id,txn_id,item_name,payment_status,cost,time) VALUES ('$id','$txn_id','$points_name','$payment_status','$payment_amount','".time()."')");  
}
// Bought $5
elseif($payment_amount == '5.00') {
$points_amount = '30';
$points_energy = '500'; 
$points_name = '30 Points And 500 Energy';
// Update Database
$update_user = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points=(points+".$points_amount."),energy=(energy+".$points_energy.") WHERE id=".$id."");
$add_trans = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id,txn_id,item_name,payment_status,cost,time) VALUES ('$id','$txn_id','$points_name','$payment_status','$payment_amount','".time()."')");  
}
// Bought $10
elseif($payment_amount == '10.00') {
$points_amount = '70';
$points_energy = '1200';    
$points_name = '70 Points And 1,200 Energy';
// Update Database
$update_user = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points=(points+".$points_amount."),energy=(energy+".$points_energy.") WHERE id=".$id."");
$add_trans = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id,txn_id,item_name,payment_status,cost,time) VALUES ('$id','$txn_id','$points_name','$payment_status','$payment_amount','".time()."')");  
}
// Bought $20
elseif($payment_amount == '20.00') {
$points_amount = '155';
$points_energy = '3000';    
$points_name = '155 Points And 3,000 Energy';
// Update Database
$update_user = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points=(points+".$points_amount."),energy=(energy+".$points_energy.") WHERE id=".$id."");
$add_trans = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id,txn_id,item_name,payment_status,cost,time) VALUES ('$id','$txn_id','$points_name','$payment_status','$payment_amount','".time()."')");  
}
// Bought $50
elseif($payment_amount == '50.00') {
$points_amount = '320';
$points_energy = '7500';    
$points_name = '320 Points And 7,500 Energy';
// Update Database
$update_user = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points=(points+".$points_amount."),energy=(energy+".$points_energy.") WHERE id=".$id."");
$add_trans = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id,txn_id,item_name,payment_status,cost,time) VALUES ('$id','$txn_id','$points_name','$payment_status','$payment_amount','".time()."')");  
}
// Bought $100
elseif($payment_amount == '100.00') {
$points_amount = '666';
$points_energy = '20000';   
$points_name = '666 Points And 20,000 Energy';
// Update Database
$update_user = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points=(points+".$points_amount."),energy=(energy+".$points_energy.") WHERE id=".$id."");
$add_trans = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id,txn_id,item_name,payment_status,cost,time) VALUES ('$id','$txn_id','$points_name','$payment_status','$payment_amount','".time()."')");  
}
}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Updated the code ::

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<?php require 'connect.php' ?>
<?php
// check if logged into PsychoWars
if(!$id) {
    die('Error: Not Logged In! Contact Us With The Transaction ID!'); 
}

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
} 
else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    break;
}
fclose ($fp);

// PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
// 1. Make sure the payment status is "Completed"   
if ((strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) && ($_POST['payment_status'] == 'Completed') && ($receiver_email == 'bad.karma12323@gmail.com')) {
    $errmsg = '';   // stores errors from fraud checks

    $points_amount="";

    switch ($payment_amount){

        case "5.00":
            $points_amount = '30';
            $points_energy = '500'; 
            break;

        case "10.00":
            $points_amount = '70';
            $points_energy = '1200'; 
            break;

        case "20.00":
            $points_amount = '155';
            $points_energy = '3000'; 
            break;  

        case "50.00":
            $points_amount = '320';
            $points_energy = '7500'; 
            break;              

        case "100.00":
            $points_amount = '666';
            $points_energy = '20000'; 
            break;      

    }

    //Only update the database if one of the above conditions is met.
    if (strlen($points_amount)>0){

        //format $points_name
        $points_name=sprintf("%s Points And %s Energy",number_format($points_amount),number_format($points_energy));

        // Update Database
        $update_user = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points=(points+".$points_amount."),energy=(energy+".$points_energy.") WHERE id=".$id."");
        $add_trans = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id,txn_id,item_name,payment_status,cost,time) VALUES ('$id','$txn_id','$points_name','$payment_status','$payment_amount','".time()."')");   
        $to      = 'bad.karma12323@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'PsychoWars Point Purchase';
        $message = '

        Thank you for your purchase

        -------------------------
        Item :: '.$points_name.'
        Cost :: $'.$payment_amount.'
        -------------------------';

        mail($to, $subject, $message);
    }
    else {
        $to = 'bad.karma12323@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'PsychoWars Point Purchase';
        $message = '

        There was an error with your purchase!

        -------------------------
        Item :: '.$points_name.'
        Cost :: $'.$payment_amount.'
        -------------------------

        Please Contact Customer Support';

        mail($to, $subject, $message);
    }
  }  
}
?>
```

Updated the code from an answer and fixed 2 errors from it. But it's still not working and still not wanting to insert into the database, and not even sending an email to my email.

Comment: Check out [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).  If you follow those procedures you should be able to find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only update the database if the $res="INVALID" and if the email check was valid.

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
} else {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            $errmsg = '';   // stores errors from fraud checks
            // PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
            // 1. Make sure the payment status is "Completed" 
            if ($_POST['payment_status'] != 'Completed') { 
                    // simply ignore any IPN that is not completed
                exit(0); 
            } 
        }else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

            $email = $_POST['payer_email'];
            $password = mt_rand(1000, 9999);
            $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
            $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
            $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
            $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
            $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];

            // Checking email
            if($receiver_email != 'bad.karma12323@gmail.com') {
             die('Error: Paypal Email Doesn\'t Match!');
            }
        } //End of elseif's
    }
    fclose ($fp);
}
```

Here is a slightly shorter version of your code:

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<?php require 'connect.php' ?>
<?php
// check if logged into PsychoWars
if(!$id) {
    die('Error: Not Logged In! Contact Us With The Transaction ID!'); 
}

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    break;
}
fclose ($fp);

// PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
// 1. Make sure the payment status is "Completed"   
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0 && $_POST['payment_status'] == 'Completed') && $receiver_email == 'bad.karma12323@gmail.com') {
    $errmsg = '';   // stores errors from fraud checks

    $points_amount="";

    switch ($payment_amount){

        case "1.00":
            $points_amount = '500';
            $points_energy = '500'; 
            break;

        case "5.00":
            $points_amount = '30';
            $points_energy = '500'; 
            break;

        case "10.00":
            $points_amount = '70';
            $points_energy = '1200'; 
            break;

        case "20.00":
            $points_amount = '155';
            $points_energy = '3000'; 
            break;  

        case "50.00":
            $points_amount = '320';
            $points_energy = '7500'; 
            break;              

        case "100.00":
            $points_amount = '666';
            $points_energy = '20000'; 
            break;      

    }

    //Only update the database if one of the above conditions is met.
    if (strlen($points_amount)>0){

        //format $points_name
        $points_name=sprintf("%s Points And %s Energy",number_format($points_amount),number_format($points_energy));

        // Update Database
        $update_user = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points=(points+".$points_amount."),energy=(energy+".$points_energy.") WHERE id=".$id."");
        $add_trans = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id,txn_id,item_name,payment_status,cost,time) VALUES ('$id','$txn_id','$points_name','$payment_status','$payment_amount','".time()."')");          
    }
}
```

}

Hope this help.

Comment: Well, I updated the question with your coding, I fixed 2 errors and added for it to send an email but it's still not working. I hope you can find a solution! Any help I am Grateful for!

Comment: Put code to send an email to you before the `if ((strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) && ($_POST['payment_status'] == 'Completed') && ($receiver_email == 'bad.karma12323@gmail.com')) ` statement to see what the $res, $_POST['payment_status'] and $receiver_email fields contain. One or more of these fields do not contain what you expect.

Comment: Wait.. This line of code here: `if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
` Should the `== 0` Be a `== 1`

Comment: `if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) ` is correct. If $res equals 'VERIFIED' it will return a 0.

Comment: Well without an actual purchase, I manually entered the url, and this is what the `$res` variable was = HTTP/1.0 200 OK

Comment: You can simulate a transaction using Pay Pal's IPN simulator.

Comment: I've tried that and it won't email me or insert the variables I have to insert into a text file, Do I need to change the `$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
` To `$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); For it to work correctly?
`

Comment: This is what I had used on a prior project:     //next 2 lines are for the sandbox
 //$response= file_get_contents('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?'.$req);
 //$recemail='seller@paypalsandbox.com';
 
 //next 2 lines are for live environment
 $response= file_get_contents('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?'.$req);

Comment: The address should read 'h t t p s://www.' before the sandbox.paypal.com for testing purposes.

Comment: Well, I think I figured it out, It started showing the error message that shows if their's Not an id `if(!$id)` But I'm logged in, I use sessions so not sure why it's doing that